# Is there a pair of tuples N, M of prime numbers which (a) have the same product, and (b) whose partial products have the same sum?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, combinatorial-number-theory

If N is a finite list of numbers, let $p(N)$ be the product of the numbers in N, that is, $$p(N)=\Pi_{i=1}^{|N|}N_i$$ and let $s(N)$ be the sum of the partial products of the numbers in N, that is $$s(N)=\Sigma_{k=1}^{|N|}\left(\Pi_{i=1}^kN_i\right)$$

Is there a pair of lists $N\neq M$ for which $p(N)=p(M)$ and $s(N)=s(M)$?

What if they only contain odd numbers 3 or higher?

What if $N$ and $M$ only contain prime numbers? Only odd primes?

What if they only contain elements of $\{3,7,19\}$? (This is the case I'm most interested in)

It seems possible that there's no such (distinct) $N$ and $M$ for the last case, but I've no idea how to prove that.

Comment: If N and M contain only primes, then they must be the same (up to ordering) because they must contain exactly the primes from the prime factorization of p(N)=p(M). This is because of the uniqueness of prime factorization.

Comment: that's right. The question is whether different orderings N and M can give the same s(.)

Comment: So you're looking for cases like s(2,8,3,7) = s(3,7,2,8) = 402, but then preferably using odd primes?

Comment: With odd primes s(3,13,7,11) = s(7,11,3,13)  = 3318 works.

Comment: My computer found s(7,3,3,3,5,19)=s(5,19,7,3,3,3)=21774
and s(19,7,3,17,17)=s(17,17,7,19,3)=122553, but if I try just the three primes 3,7,19 it finds nothing for lists of length 15 or less.

Comment: Thanks @JaapScherphuis, this is awesome